# Testes paralelos usando Selenium/TestNg e Banco de dados

Tags: testes, selenium-webdriver, paralelismo

Tenho 1165 testes cases e isso ta demorando 36 horas para rodar + rodar isso tudo em 3 diferentes browsers e estou ficando louca com essa demora.

A minha dúvida é se tem como rodar testes paralelos usando selenium/testng sendo que suas classes precisam acessar o mesmo banco de dados?

Vou tentar explicar melhor.

Digamos que eu tenha a classe chamada `TesteParaCartaoDeCredito`, essa classe tem vários testes dentro que acessam o banco de dados, como por exemplo, criar novo cartão de credito, alterar os limites, bloquear cartão e por ai vai.

Hoje se eu tento rodar em paralelo, usando chrome e firefox por exemplo, meu segundo test case sempre falha, porque o primeiro browser já rodou o mesmo teste e já alterou isso lá no banco de dados (por exemplo o primeiro browser rodou o teste de bloquear o cartão e ai o segundo browser quando roda qualquer outro, falha).

Qualquer ideia é bem vinda.

Answer (score 1):

No seu teste rondando em paralelo você consegue clonar a sua base? Caso positivo você poderia ter duas bases para rodar em paralelo. Nesse caso uma não iria interferir na outra porque estão apontando para bases diferentes